# Is it possible to create a soap bubble in space?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, surface-tension, bubbles

since space does not contain air, is it possible to create a soap bubble without air in **space** or in **vacuum** and can can you explain why so? OR will there be any possibilities for a bubble in such kind of environment? OR will a bubble exist without air in vacuum or space?

Comment: The "wall" of a soap bubble is is an _aqueous solution_ with a high surface tension. Soap bubbles generally "pop" when too much of the water evaporates out of that solution. The water would evaporate _very_ quickly in vacuum.

Comment: Related: [How long would a bubble made in the ISS last?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277831/238167)

Answer (score 1):

As all soap bubbles have a fleeting existence, one created in space would have an even more fleeting existence. Since space contains no air how a bubble could be formed would be different than in an atmosphere. Pragmatically it seems that one would first create a ball of liquid then blow an air bubble into it via something like a straw. Another method might be having a ball of liquid and then injecting a solid pellet of some chemical that would sublime into a gas, like solid CO2.

I'll point out that your question just says "in space" which doesn't eliminate the possibility of creating soap bubbles inside a space ship with air. This however seems to be out of scope.

Comment: I think blowing air inside a drop will come to its surface and burst as soon as it is blown.

Comment: What do you think would draw the air to the surface?  There have been some [fun experiments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFLo07H2p8U) done with air bubbles in this way.  While they were done in atmosphere, not vacuum, they do show that fluids behave strangely in zero g and can defy intuition.

Comment: Obviously you'll only use a tiny amount of pressure. I don't think one oxygen molecule at whatever the temperature there is is going to rip it apart, will it? Between that and infinity lies a point for nice, neat bubbles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could form a bubble in space. A bubble exists when there is equilibrium between the surface tension of the enveloping material and the positive pressure differential between the gas inside and that outside. There's no need for the gas outside to have any particular pressure.